# R: forecast::accuracy() Vs Metrics::accuracy() Functions Results Not the Same

Tags: r, metrics, arima, forecast

I am testing for the `RMSE` of a forecast and observed that the two `forecast::accuracy()[2]` and `Metrics::accuracy()` are not the same. In fact, the latter is even `0`

```
set.seed(289805)
ts1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1) # the series I want to forecast for
train_ts1 <- head(ts1, length(ts1) - 2) # the part of series I want to project int the future time
test_ts1 <- tail(ts1, length(ts1) - length(train_ts1)) # the part of series I want to compare my forecast with

set.seed(837530)
ts2 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ma = 0.8, order = c(0, 0, 1)), sd = 1) # the second series, part of which I want to train
train_ts2 <- head(ts2, length(ts2) - 2) # trainning part of second series
test_ts2 <- tail(ts2, length(ts2) - length(train_ts2)) # do not seem to need this part of the series
fcast <- forecast::forecast(train_ts1, model = forecast::auto.arima(train_ts2), h = 2)$mean # my 
forecast using the best model from trainning set of second series
forecast::accuracy(fcast, test_ts1)[2] # RMSE for the forecast
# [1] 0.6412488
Metrics::accuracy(test_ts1, fcast)
# [1] 0
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may check the source code.  For `Metrics`, it is `1 - ce(actual, predicted))`

Comment: I do not see it that way you commented,this is what I can see `Metrics::accuracy(actual, predicted)`. Besides, what is your `ce`?

Comment: You can type the function name after loading the package.  If you type `ce` on the console `return(mean(actual != predicted))`

Comment: I can't relate to this your function please

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.  I meant to say that if there is a difference in value, it would be related to the difference in its  implementation